# how to display and add partition in the SUN solaris OS?

Tags: partition, solaris, fdisk

how to display and add partition in the SUN solaris OS?

Linux version is

```
uname -a
SunOS SMS 5.10 Generic_141414-02 sun4v sparc SUNW,Netra-T2000

#fdisk -l
fdisk: illegal option -- l
Usage: fdisk
[ -A id:act:bhead:bsect:bcyl:ehead:esect:ecyl:rsect:numsect ]
[ -b masterboot ]
[ -D id:act:bhead:bsect:bcyl:ehead:esect:ecyl:rsect:numsect ]
[ -F fdisk_file ] [ -h ] [ -o offset ] [ -P fill_patt ] [ -s size ]
[ -S geom_file ] [ [ -v ] -W { creat_fdisk_file | - } ]
[ -w | r | d | n | I | B | E | g | G | R | t | T ] rdevice

Detailed help is available with the -h option.

# lvdisplay
ksh: lvdisplay:  not found

#df -h
/dev/md/dsk/a100        15G   6.2G   8.9G    42%    /disk
/dev/md/dsk/a111         96G    42G    53G    45%    /storage
/dev/md/dsk/a112       191G   159G    30G    85%    /files
```

Answer (score 1):

to list physical disk use

```
echo | format
```

which will give

```
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t5000c50786c8513Bd0 <SEAGATE-ST930663SSUN300G-0D70-279.40GB>
          /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000c50786c8513b
          /dev/chassis/SYS/HDD0/disk
(...)
Specify disk (enter its number): Specify disk (enter its number):
```

to see about metaset use `metastat` command

(I no longer have a host with metadevice, I can't give sample)

Comment: actually i want to add one more partition on  /dev/md/dsk/a113       500G   0G    500G    100%    /backupfiles... How can i use the command to add the partition ? Before i add, how cn i use the command to check whether have enough partition?   i use format command , its show 4 disk available? but i am not sure which disk to be choose.

Answer (score 0):

As Archemar noted, you probably want to use the `format` command, as well as the `metastat` command for the /dev/md/dsk/* drives.  But I suggest you read up on slicing and dicing in Solaris first as it's different than in Linux.

Note, I don't know/remember where they added functionality in format, to advise/warn if something is being used on a drive (SVM, UFS, ZFS, LU) (see example output).  However since you're on a older kernel patch, you're format cmd might not have it.

> [9] pfexec format 
>   Searching for disks...done
>
> AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
>
> ```
>    0. c0t0d0 <SUN146G cyl 14087 alt 2 hd 24 sec 848>
>       /pci@0,600000/pci@0/pci@8/pci@0/scsi@1/sd@0,0
>
>    1. c0t1d0 <SUN146G cyl 14087 alt 2 hd 24 sec 848>  
>       /pci@0,600000/pci@0/pci@8/pci@0/scsi@1/sd@1,0
> ```
>
> Specify disk (enter its number): 0
>
> selecting c0t0d0 [disk formatted]
>
> /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0 is part of SVM volume stripe:d10. Please see
>   metaclear(1M). /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s1 is part of SVM volume stripe:d11.
>   Please see metaclear(1M). /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3 is part of SVM volume
>   stripe:d13. Please see metaclear(1M). /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s4 is part of SVM
>   volume stripe:d14. Please see metaclear(1M). /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s5 is part
>   of SVM volume stripe:d15. Please see metaclear(1M). /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s6
>   is part of active ZFS pool rpool. Please see zpool(1M).
>   /dev/dsk/c0t0d0s7 contains an SVM mdb. Please see metadb(1M).

The /dev/md/dsk/* were built with the SVM (Solaris Volume Manager) commands.  It's a legacy mechanism for managing disk storage using software RAID.  The preferred choice for Solaris 10+ systems is to use ZFS--which I also suggest you use over SVM.

Also note, that I find it curious that your `df -h` output only showed (3) filesystems -- neither of which is a root FS.  I'm assuming you abbreviated it.

Comment: ZFS was NOT the preferred file system for the initial version of Solaris 10 nor for a number of years afterwords.

Comment: True, as it didn't make it into the GA of v10.  I was making a generalization of how the majority of Solaris SAs would feel.

Comment: actually i want to add one more partition on  /dev/md/dsk/a113       500G   0G    500G    100%    /backupfiles... How can i use the command to add the partition ? Before i add, how cn i use the command to check whether have enough partition?   i use format command , its show 4 disk available? but i am not sure which disk to be choose.

Comment: I don't see a dev a113 listed in your output, but if it's there already, run `metastat a113` which will show you the configuration of a113 including the drives & slices used.
You'd then need to look at the partition table for those drives to know if there's any free space remaining.
And I still reco you read up on slicing and dicing on Solaris.